# Lean Eloquent Results ->with() Eager Loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query I am working on that feeds into a javascript engine where there is a lot of information returned that isn't used in the javascript. The results are over 1MB and some of that is because of some eager loading. Here is the query:

```
$customers = Customer::where('customers.office_id', $officeid)
    ->where("customers.parent_id", null)
    ->with('lastAppointment')
    ->with('nextAppointment')
    ->select("customers.id","customers.family_id", "customers.gender", "customers.family_size", "family_value")
    ->get();
```

The relationship of `lastAppointment` creates a returned nested object with all the columns from the `appointments` table, where I really only want a single column of `start_at`

If I do a `->leftJoin()` I can limit my results using the final select like this:

```
->leftJoin(DB::raw("(select customer_id, MAX(start_at) as lastAppointment from appointments group by customer_id) as appt"), 'customers.id', '=', 'appt.customer_id')
->select("customers.id","customers.family_id", "customers.gender", "customers.family_size", "family_value", "appt.lastAppointment")
```

I am just wondering if there is a way of doing something similar using  `->with()`?

Comment: `->with('lastAppointment:_relation_id,start_at')` _relation_id is parent id or lastAppointment primary key

Comment: This was a great solution! I tried without the `_relation_id` since I really only needed the raw value but it didn't work. However, when I did it your way, I got back a much cleaner response than before `"last_appointment": {
                "customer_id": 195701,
                "start_at": "2018-07-17 11:00:00"
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
->with('lastAppointment:_relation_id,start_at')
```

where `_relation_id` is `customer_id` or primary key of `lastAppointment` correspond model: `depends on your table relation`. See docs part of **Nested Eager Loading**
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading p

Answer (score 1):

The `with` function will accept a callback as the array value of the relationship key. You then have access to the underlaying query builder instance, I think this is what you want:

```
->with(['lastAppointment' => function($query) {
    return $query->latest()->select('customer_id', 'start_at')
        ->groupBy('customer_id');
}])
```